# Script works in ISE and not SOME powershell CLI

Tags: powershell

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("********Please Select the SOURCE Directory********",0,"Directory Selecter 5000",0x1)

Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory)

{

    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"

    if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
        $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
    }
    return $folder
}

$a = Get-Folder

$wshellb = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshellb.Popup("********Please Select the DESTINATION Directory********",0,"Directory Selecter 5000",0x1)
Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory)

{

    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"

    if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
        $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
    }
    return $folder
}

$b = Get-Folder


Set-Content -Path "C:\script\scripts\script data.txt" -Value "$a" -Force
Set-Content -Path "C:\script\scripts\script data2.txt" -Value "$b" -Force
```

So this script works in ISE and if I copy/paste it into a CLI and that's it.  If I navigate to the folder in the powershell CLI and run it from there it gives me this error:

> New-Object : Cannot find type
>   [System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog]: verify that the assembly
>   containing this type is loaded. At
>   C:\script\scripts\pathingworking.ps1:8 char:19
>   +     $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
>   +                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
>
> The property 'rootfolder' cannot be found on this object. Verify that
>   the property exists and can be set. At
>   C:\script\scripts\pathingworking.ps1:9 char:5
>   +     $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\script\scripts\pathingworking.ps1:11 char:8
>   +     if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
>   +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

This error comes back twice, once for each instance of the folder selection window that is supposed to pop up.

I have tried -STA from run dialogue, shortcuts, and even from the CLI and it always gives me that error.  I have verified using [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() that the open instance of powershell is STA.  I can open a powershell CLI and navigate to the folder where the script is, invoke the script, it will give me the error, then I can copy\paste it in the same exact CLI and it works without issue.  I have also right-clicked the file in Explorer and selected "run with powershell" and it also gives me the error.  I have elevated the CLI to see if that helped with no success.

I fear this is some small oversight and hopefully someone can give me a hand.

using v1.0
windows 10

Comment: you need to add the assemblies to your script: `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: "using v1.0 windows 10" if you mean Powershell v1.0 I'm not positive that is even possible...

Comment: thank you, I really thought it was just some simple oversight.

Answer (score 3):

Cannot find type [System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog] is due to the assembly not being loaded.

load the assembly with

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"
```

Answer (score 1):

rerun's answer solves the errors, but doesn't do a whole lot of explaining. Designing a script in the ISE (which is what I do almost exclusively) is convenient because it will automatically load types and modules for you. If you plan on running the script from another CLI (Command Line Interpreter) you should make it a habit of explicitly loading needed modules and assemblies early on in the script, so that when those things are called upon later PowerShell will know what you're asking for.

Unfortunately there's no easy way to tell what you will need to do that for when it comes to what types are going to be inherently available, but a little trial and error usually points it out rather quickly, or if you look at your script and see that you are making a new object with `System.Kitchen.Pasta`, then you probably need to load the assembly for `System.Kitchen` first, so that it has the Pasta type available when you want it, so you could just include a call to load that assembly near the top of the script with no harm done.

In your specific case, as has already been pointed out, you will need to load the assembly that contains the FolderBrowserDialog box that you want to display. Adding the following as the first line of your script will resolve the errors that you are seeing:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"
```

Comment: You can dump the loaded assemblies with [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() in ISE as a starting point, but that will cause you to load stuff you don't need.

Comment: I know we have had this discussion before, but I'll say it again. Other than using the ISE for purely writing code (and Visual Studio Code is even better for that) then don't use it for development. Write the code there if you must but never run it there. Always run it in the CLI.

Comment: @EBGreen That's your opinion. I've tried VSC when it first came out, and I didn't see anything that it did better than the ISE. I'll have to try it again, I'm sure it is improved by now. I completely agree that if you are writing a script that will be executed anywhere outside of the ISE that you need to test it in the CLI. That should be the case anytime you write anything really. Test in the target conditions, to avoid the '...but it worked fine on my dev box' situation.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician My opinion. Agreed. If nothing else, VSC allows me to use a Vim plugin :)

Answer (score 0):

@rerun: Thanks, that helped me with my issue too (see [Add-type -AssemblyName "System.Web" to determine MIME-type with Powershell 7 works in ISE but not Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77292798/add-type-assemblyname-system-web-to-determine-mime-type-with-powershell-7-wor/77293392#77293392)).

I ran the command in both `powershell.exe` and the ISE (`powershell_ise.exe`). In the former, there was no assembly called `System.Web`, but I did find it in the latter.

Searching in the meantime had already helped me to figure out that `using assembly` in Powershell 7 requires a full path to the .dll.

At first I used `using assembly System.Web`, but that didn't help. With @rerun's hint I found an entry
`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll`

I used this one at the beginning of the script like this
`using assembly "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll`
and that finally did the job.

Thanks :)

---

The functioning code looks like this:

```
using assembly "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll"

$FilePath = "C:\users\Daniel\Desktop\test.pdf"

$DocExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($FilePath)
$DocMimeType  = [System.Web.MimeMapping]::GetMimeMapping($DocExtension)

Write-Output "Extension: $DocExtension `nMIME-type: $DocMimeType"
```

Comment: Note that the `System.Web` assembly is _not_ loaded by default in the ISE either. Once it is - which seemingly happens _implicitly_ once you reference a WinForms type such as `[System.Windows.Forms.Form]` - you can determine its assembly file path via one of its types as follows: `[System.Web.MimeMapping].Assembly.Location`

Comment: That referencing a well-known assembly via `using assembly System.Web` doesn't work in PowerShell (Core) 7+ is a _bug_: see [GitHub issue #11856](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11856). However, even if it _did_ work, it would load the .NET (Core) version of the assembly, which does _not_ contain the `[System.Web.MimeMapping]` type, because it has been _removed_ from .NET (.NET Core / .NET 5+). By using the full path to the  _.NET Framework_ version of the assembly from the _GAC_, you're loading the latter even in PowerShell (Core), which _happens to_ work.