# Add-type -AssemblyName "System.Web" to determine MIME-type with Powershell 7 works in ISE but not Powershell

Tags: powershell, system.web

My little script works as expected in Powershell ISE:

```
$FilePath = "C:\users\Daniel\Desktop\test.pdf"

Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Web"

$DocExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($FilePath)
$DocMimeType  = [System.Web.MimeMapping]::GetMimeMapping($DocExtension)

Write-Output "Extension: $DocExtension `nMIME-type: $DocMimeType"
```

Running it in Powershell.exe I get the following error:
Unable to find type [System.Web.MimeMapping].

I googled and ChatGPTed for an hour but still cannot find any solution that would work for me.

I want to run that code block from above in a script that gets executed with Powershell, not ISE.

Help is much appreciated, thanks

I expect the script to run in Powershell.exe too.

Answer (score 1):

The **[`System.Web.MimeMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mimemapping)** type is only supported in the **legacy .NET Framework**
that underlies the legacy ***Windows PowerShell* edition**, which is the only edition supported in the obsolescent ISE.<sup>[1]</sup>

- **Note**: This **type isn't worth using, as it is no longer actively maintained**, whereas the **list of media types (formerly known as MIME types) continues to evolve**.
  For instance, it doesn't know about the fairly common `application/json` (`.json`) and `text/csv` (`.csv`) media types.

The modern **.NET (Core) framework** underlying the modern, cross-platform **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition** ***doesn't have this
type*** anymore.

The **third-party [`MimeTypes`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MimeTypes) NuGet package** offers an **alternative**, but use *from PowerShell* is nontrivial, especially in *Windows PowerShell*; a ***PowerShell (Core)-only* solution is feasible**, however - see the bottom section. The **next section shows a *cross-edition* solution**, i.e. one that works in both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core).

---

***Cross-PowerShell-edition* solution**:

The `MimeTypes` NuGet package is built on the Node.js [mime-db](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db) project, which offers its list of media-type definitions in the form of an online JSON file that is updated periodically.

That JSON file can be downloaded and parsed on demand:

```bash
# Extract the filename extension without the leading '.'
$extension = [IO.Path]::GetExtension('c:\path\to\some\file.txt').Substring(1)

# Download and parse the list of media types (MIME types) via
# https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db,
# convert from JSON, and look up the extension at hand.
(
  Invoke-RestMethod https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jshttp/mime-db@master/db.json
).psobject.Properties.Where({ $_.Value.extensions -contains $extension }, 'First').Name
```

The above yields `'text/plain'`.

**Important**:

- The JSON format may change in the future, so using a *specific release* of the JSON file is advisable.
- The wrapper function below:

  - Locks in v1.52.0, the version current as of this writing.
  - Downloads the JSON file on every call, which hurts performance.
    Consider caching it.

**`Get-MediaTypeByFilename` function wrapper**:

Assuming the function, whose source code is below, is defined, here's a sample call:

```bash
# -> 'text/plain', 'text/html'
Get-MediaTypeByFilename foo.txt, bar.html
```

***Cross-edition* `Get-MediaTypeByFilename` source code**:

```bash
function Get-MediaTypeByFilename {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string[]] $Filename
  )
  begin { 
    # Download and parse the list of media types (MIME types) via
    # https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db.
    # NOTE: 
    #  * For better performance consider caching the JSON file.
    #  * A fixed release is targeted, to ensure that future changes to the JSON
    #    format do not break the command.
    $mediaTypes = (
      Invoke-RestMethod https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jshttp/mime-db@v1.52.0/db.json
    ).psobject.Properties
  }
  process {
    foreach ($name in $Filename) {
      # Find the matching media type by filename extension.
      $matchingMediaType = 
        $mediaTypes.Where(
          { $_.Value.extensions -contains [IO.Path]::GetExtension($name).Substring(1) }, 
          'First'
        ).Name
      # Use a fallback type, if no match was found.
      if (-not $matchingMediaType) { $matchingMediaType = 'application/octet-stream' }
      $matchingMediaType # output
    }
  }
}
```

---

***PowerShell (Core) 7+-only* solution**:

The [`MimeTypes`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MimeTypes) NuGet package a source code-only package that requires compilation, which you can do on demand with `Add-Type`.
However, because the source code uses newer C# features that aren't supported in *Windows PowerShell*'s `Add-Type`, the following function works in PowerShell (Core) 7+ only.

Sample call:

```bash
# PowerShell (Core) 7+ only.
# -> 'text/plain', 'text/html'
Get-MediaTypeByFilename foo.txt, bar.html
```

**Important**:

- The code below downloads the *latest* version of the `MimeTypes` source code directly from GitHub (via [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod)), directly from the `master` branch.

  - If, for predictability, you want to lock in a *specific* version, use a URL such as the following, based on the version current as of this writing, v2.4.1: [`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khellang/MimeTypes/v2.4.1/src/MimeTypes/MimeTypes.cs.pp`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khellang/MimeTypes/v2.4.1/src/MimeTypes/MimeTypes.cs.pp)
- Use of [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) for on-demand compilation incurs a once-per-session performance penalty.

***PowerShell (Core)-only* `Get-MediaTypeByFilename` source code**:

```bash
# PowerShell 7+ only.
function Get-MediaTypeByFilename {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string[]] $Filename
  )
  begin { 
    if (-not (Get-Variable -ErrorAction Ignore -ValueOnly IsCoreCLR)) {
      throw 'This command runs only in PowerShell (Core) 7+.'
    }
    # Download and compile a helper class, via
    # https://github.com/khellang/MimeTypes
    # Use a namespace of your choice for the compiled type; this is just an example.
    $rootnamespace = 'net.same2u.web'
    Add-Type (
      (
        Invoke-RestMethod https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khellang/MimeTypes/master/src/MimeTypes/MimeTypes.cs.pp
      ).Replace('$rootnamespace$', $rootnamespace)
    )      
    $method = ([type] "$rootnamespace.MimeTypes")::GetMimeType
  }
  process {
    foreach ($name in $Filename) {
      $method.Invoke($name)
    }
  }
}
```

---

<sup>[1]  The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks mklement0, but I found an easier solution.

I ran the command "[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()" in both, Powershell.exe and ISE.exe. In Powershell there was no assembly called System.Web, in ISE.exe I found one though.

Searching in the meantime had already helped me to figure out that "using assembly" in Powershell 7 requires a full path to the .dll.

So I replaced my original "using assembly System.Web" with the path I found using the command about to
`using assembly "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll"`

---

The functioning code looks like this:

```
using assembly "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll"

$FilePath = "C:\users\Daniel\Desktop\test.pdf"

$DocExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($FilePath)
$DocMimeType  = [System.Web.MimeMapping]::GetMimeMapping($DocExtension)

Write-Output "Extension: $DocExtension `nMIME-type: $DocMimeType"
```

Comment: Nicely done (a bit more work would be needed if you also want to support 32-bit versions of PowerShell and ARM machines). However, I've realized that `[System.Web.MimeMapping]` isn't worth using anymore, given that it is no longer updated and already doesn't know about fairly common MIME types such as `application/json` and `text/csv`. Please see my update for a cross-edition solution that doesn't rely on this type.

Comment: As an inconsequential aside: You can pass full file paths to `[System.Web.MimeMapping]::GetMimeMapping()` - no need to extract the filename extension first.